# Writing different tests for different environments

Tags: unit-tests, protractor, angular, testing-environment, e2e

We didn't implement automated deployment yet to our Angular 7 project, so environment-based variables (e.g baseUrl) are changed manually, causing the application to crash after deployment a lot due to wrong variable values.

Does it make sense to write some environment-specific tests to ensure that the correct values are being passed and set and how to go about this (e.g. conditional statements based on node_env, separate test files for each environment, ...)?

Things I want to keep in mind are:

- Code coverage
- Applying DRY to not repeat tests that wouldn't be different based on different environments
- Should I use E2E or unit tests or both for the mentioned purpose.

Comment: To me this is a valid question. Having to manually change the `baseURL` seems like a design flaw. It should be testes via `unit testing` yet again - if the variable is set manually there is not much to test, as the `url` is hardcoded.

Comment: @Moro I appreciate that. It definitely is, but in real life, I can't just automate everything, so I am trying to improve the application step by step, and for me the wrong values for things like baseURL are a huge headache, even with environment variables things can get missy. That's why I am posting the question so see the best way to ensure that these variables are set and are set correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if it makes sense to write some environment-specific tests ?

Absolutely!  This is also frequently the job of smoke tests which basically assert that the latest deployment was successfull with very simple tests such as 'can I reach the page or do I get a 404'

Testing the tests is an essential part of any quality automation system.
You should generally test the tests for:

- Environment variables set correctly *
- Page Object Duplicates
- Page Object Orphans
- Test Code complexity
- Test code syntax and linting
- Test code quality

In your case smoke tests and environment variable tests should be used.

*You'll need to think this through.  Obviously static code 'does x = 1' does not respect different environments. Also you want to avoid statement like does `url = x` and `username = y` and `password = z`.  Think through a  system that forces you to update these items.  Maybe check the update timestamp of the variables file, maybe use a deployment step or sha to do this.

Ultimately:

Automate the entire process.  When you need variables for a given environment, make sure they have to be updated as an automated step of the deployment process.

Comment: I definitely need to automate the process, but this of course a long process. Meanwhile, I think smoke tests are good, I found a very good example https://www.letscodejavascript.com/v3/transcripts/lessons_learned/4#tabs.

Just to be clear, when and where should I run the smoke tests? in a duplicate (staging server) environment or in the production environment?

Comment: The environment you are deploying to. If they fail you stop or rollback immediately

Comment: I.e. production in this case